# How many common conventions exist for inserting sounds made by the author?

Tags: style, blog

**Is it (*sniff) or (/sniff)?**

I’m reminiscing nostalgically on a personal blog and I want to insert an onomatopoeic sniff.

> My days spent raiding dungeons in Hibernia are long over (/sniff) but …

I want the reader to know that I actually audibly sniffed a nostalgic sniff as I wrote that. I know there are no rules. I want to know what common conventions are out there and where they come from. I also feel that I am out of touch with what the younger cool kids are doing these days.

1. **(/sniff)** This looks like an “emote” command common in (older?) online RPGs. I used to use this one a lot but refrain these days as the style choice is one only appreciated by a certain subculture of online gamers.
2. **(*sniff)** I have seen this style before. I don’t know where it came from but it looks a bit like a comment in computer code.
3. **(sniff)** Just putting the onomatopoeia in brackets seems a little unimaginative.

Are there other popularly recognised styles for inserting onomatopoeia out there?

Answer (score 4):

What I have seen is not `*sniff`, but `*sniff*`, which, I believe, comes from [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (which is [used on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well), where text framed by asterisks is rendered as *italic*.

The other common markup for onomatopoeia is, in fact, italics.

As I see it, the conventions are:

> How sad. *Sniff.*

```
How sad. *sniff*
```

I have never seen `*sniff*` in print and would use it online only.

Comment: The Markdown connection. That's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add some information in addition to what's answer.

Firstly, it is commonplace to use italics to convey onomatopoeic sounds:

> The rock fell down with a *crash*.
>
> With a deafening *whack*, the saucepan man was hit over the head by his saucepan.

However, I wouldn't use it for **verbs** that imply **sound.**

For example:

> The saucepan man grunted.
>
> The saucepan man was cold, and he sniffed every two seconds.

---

I would advise you not to use things like *sniff or (sniff) because you are writing a blog, and not chatting in an online game :).

Comment: On a blog actually. I don't intend for the sniff to be parted of any sentence.

Comment: How embarrassing! I didn't read your question accurately. Still, the same applies @lukejanicke